# How to show mysql Database Stored image as a background in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel.

I am trying to show the MySQL image in the background but I can't.

I have used this code to show but it is not working at all

```
<div class=" banner-services-bg"style="background-image: url('{{ $pageData->image }}');">
```

I want to tell you that I can see $pagedata with the dd() function and the image is also there
and I have public>images folder structure

and also I can see my image directly on the page with this code

```
<img src="{{ url($pageData->image) }}"alt="" />
```

attributes i got through dd function

> #attributes:  [▼
> "id" => 36
> "title" => "Best Car Rental Offers"
> "slug" => "car-rental"
> "image" => "uploads/1/2023-03/car_with_driver.jpg"
> ]

Comment: How you stored image in database ?

Comment: "but I can't" - what does that mean? What is the code doing instead?

Comment: i have stored image through admin panel

Comment: but i cant mean i cant able to see image on view page as  background

Comment: What is the contents of `$pageData->image`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is the markup generated as expected?

Comment: all attributes got with dd function

  #attributes: array:16 [▼
    "id" => 36
    "admin_id" => 1
    "title" => "Best Car Rental Offers"
    "slug" => "car-rental"
    "description" => "<h4 style="font-family: var(--font-primary); font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.2; color: rgb(40, 39, 38); margin: 0px 0px 8px; padding: 0px; -webkit-tap-highlig ▶"
    "excerpt" => "<p>car rental</p>"
    "image" => "uploads/1/2023-03/car_with_driver.jpg"

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - how does the **generated** markup look like? Does it probably contain a background image URL that yields a 404?

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by **editing** it.  Code / data / error info does not belong in the comments. This isn't a standard discusssion forum. There's an [edit] button just under your question's blue tags.

Comment: Check your browser's Network tool while the page is loading, observe the HTTP request to load the image file, and observe the response code it returns. If you don't get 200 OK, then double-check that the URL it's returning is a valid URL and that your webserver has read permissions on the file. (e.g. a 404 error would indicate the wrong URL was used, a 403 would indicate a permissions error. Other errors may occur too but those are the most common ones.)

Comment: error has been resolved thanks

Comment: Your browser's View Source... and Inspect... features are your friends. Right click where the image should be and Inspect it. You'll be able to see exactly the HTML generated by your Laravel / php program. From your question it looks like you're generating `src="uploads/1/2023-03/car_with_driver.jpg"` URLs. Ordinarily URLS for images should start with `/`, otherwise they're dependent on the path to the URL of the referring page.

Comment: @Ahmad Considering all the work people here did to help you, it would be polite to write an answer to your question saying what you did to fix the problem.

Comment: I have used this code 

style="background-image: url({{ url($pageData->image) }});"

and now i can see my database image as a background 

thanks to all who reply on my post

Comment: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not part of the comments! Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because to comments aren't searchable, and don't gain you reputation! Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works if you need to. The [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) article from the help centre is also relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main resons!

1. Your `div` has `0` width and height!
2. Your image address escaped!

Try this:

```
<div class=" banner-services-bg" style="width: 100%; aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; backgriund-size: cover; background-image: url('{!! $pageData->image !!}');">
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this code

```
style="background-image: url({{ url($pageData->image) }});"
```

and now i can see my database image as a background

thanks to all who reply on my post